# Targeting the element from the background

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, let say I have 3 container background that I can't access with, inside that container I have a button that do something, ex: open a new window, alert and modal.

If I want to click the background and target to that button to do the same thing in the same container, how to do that?

I tried using target or current target, but doesn't work.

```js
const linkButton = document.querySelector(".link");
const alertButton = document.querySelector(".alert");
const backgroundClick = document.querySelector(".background");

linkButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
 console.log("test");
})

alertButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
 alert("alert");
})

backgroundClick.addEventListener("click", function () {
 console.log("working");
})
```

```css
body {
  color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.background {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* The button used to close the modal */
.closebtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.closebtn:hover,
.closebtn:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

/*Open modal*/

/* The modal's background */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/* Display the modal when targeted */
.modal:target {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
}

/* The modal box */
.modal-dialog {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
        <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_" style="display: inline-block;">
            <button>Button Link</button>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="background">
        <button class="alert">Button Alert</button>
    </div>

    <div class="background">
        <a href="#id01">
            <Open class="alert">Open Modal</button>
        </a>

        <div id="id01" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <header class="container">
                        <a href="#" class="closebtn">×</a>
                        <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                    </header>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of concept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: @MihirKumar I don't think so, my problem is more about how to target an element

Comment: **background that I can't access with** can't access with what?

Comment: @Barmar, Using drupal, so in case if someone suggest in easy way to add a link in that container then I can't do that, so I need to target that button

Comment: What is `<open>`? Is that supposed to be `<button>`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, sorry mistypo, suppose to be button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.querySelector("button")` to find the button inside the `.background` DIV, and trigger its `click` event.

You also need to loop over all the `.background` DIVs to add listeners to all of them.

I use `e.stopPropagation()` in the button event handlers. Otherwise, the click events will bubble out to the backgrounds, and you'll get an infinite loop of events.

```js
const linkButton = document.querySelector(".link");
const alertButton = document.querySelector(".alert");
const backgroundClick = document.querySelectorAll(".background");

linkButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("test");
  e.stopPropagation();
})

alertButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  alert("alert");
  e.stopPropagation();
})

backgroundClick.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let button = this.querySelector("button");
  button.click();
}));
```

```css
body {
  color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.background {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* The button used to close the modal */

.closebtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.closebtn:hover,
.closebtn:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}


/*Open modal*/


/* The modal's background */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


/* Display the modal when targeted */

.modal:target {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
}


/* The modal box */

.modal-dialog {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_" style="display: inline-block;">
    <button>Button Link</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="background">
  <button class="alert">Button Alert</button>
</div>

<div class="background">
  <a href="#id01">
    <button class="alert">Open Modal</button>
  </a>

  <div id="id01" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <header class="container">
          <a href="#" class="closebtn">×</a>
          <h2>Modal Header</h2>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working, I thought I need to use target or current target, thanks for the answer

Comment: You can do it that way, too.